# What is the DubaiCoin, what does it do, how does it work and what platform is it based on?

Tags: altcoin

Please help on specifics. Provide any additional information you consider relevant.

Answer (score 1):

DubaiCoin is a mixed proof-of-work/proof-of-stake altcoin created in 2016. It's stated purpose is to facilitate commerce in the Arab world. The mining and distribution model was pioneered by MintCoin and BlackCoin in 2014.

In 2017, the DubaiCoin team created a new ethereum-based chain, ArabianChain, and distributed the new token to holders through a "coin swap" procedure. This process entails "burning" DubaiCoin to receive tokens on the new chain. As with many coin swaps, the old chain remains active and many people were either unable or chose not to participate in the swap.

As with many altcoins, the stated purpose may underpin an effort to manipulate the market price in order to generate profits for large early holders of the cryptocurrency.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about this one : https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1811194.0 (DBIX) then it's a fork of Ethereum. So it work like Ethereum and it can do what Ethereum can do.